# formatting issues with printout statement, doubles java

Tags: java, printing, format

I'm a newby java guy trying to get my print out statement to format decimal placements.. I know that %.2f works, but for whatever reason when I try to apply the %.2f it bombs.... Not sure what to do.. any advice? thanks in advance!

```
credits = int 

raise = double

System.out.printf("An undergraduate resident student taking " + credits + " currently pays $" + "%,.2f",credtotal);

System.out.println("\n");

System.out.printf("with a increase in tuition of " + (trying to format here) raise + ", per credit will become " + raisecredund +  ", and an undergraduate resident taking " + credits +  " credits" + " will pay $" +"%,.2f",(credits*(raise*245.73))+ credtotal);;
```

Comment: Moved original comment to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 final String str1 = String.format("An undergraduate resident student taking %d currently pays $%.2f",credits, credtotal);
```

**EDIT**: I didn't notice that you were using `printf`. You were close:

```
 System.out.printf("An undergraduate resident student taking %d currently pays $%.2f", credits,credtotal);
```

Using your first example string, you supply the formatting characters inline and then provide an argument for each placeholder. Assuming `credtotal` is a double and knowing `credits` is `int`, the above would yield (with respective values assigned)

```
An undergraduate resident student taking 1 currently pays $2.00
```

See [creating formatted strings section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using `"%,.2f"` with a comma which I don't think is legal.  `%.2f` will print the number to 2 decimal places.

If you want to include a comma ever 3 places like in money you should use a DecimalFormat
     `DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");`